# html table to powerpoint

Tags: html, powerpoint

I have an odd request. I have made an application that produces an `html/printable` invoice in a table format.

What I am trying to do is figure out how to take such a table, which may have 3 or as many as 20 rows on it depending on who's using it, and paste it into power point.
It seems to do it, but the result varies.

Any idea on where to start? I'll buy something if I have to!

Comment: Does copy and paste not work?

Comment: With varied results-sometimes it's too big for the slide and does not provide a way to resize

Answer (score -1):

Select  the first field of the HTML table by double-clicking it

Then press Shift+end keys (or Ctrl+Shift+end )

This will  select the entire table.
Now you can copy the table and paste it wherever you want to

You can also automate the entire process for multiple tables